# Code run in php 5.3.6 but not run 5.1.6

Tags: php, oop

Here I added my code

class1.php

```
<?php
     class class1
     {
         public function test_class(){
            return "text_class";
         }
     }
 ?>
```

class2.php

```
<?php
     require_once "class1.php";
     class class2{
         public function __construct(){
              $this->classs=new class1();
         } 
         public function test_class2(){
             echo $this->classs->test_class();
             return "text_class";
          }
      }
 ?>
```

when run class2.php execution stops in class2.php contructor.no error or warnings are not display.

i am using php version 5.1.6

Comment: Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php if your system isn't set to catch and display errors by default.

Comment: i included top of class error_reporting(E_ALL) but not working

Comment: see the answer given below then

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your class2 file you should define property then you can use this property anywhere in your class.

Look this:

```
include_once "class1.php";
     class class2 
     {
         private $classs;

         public function __construct()
         {
              $this->classs = new class1();
         } 

         public function test_class2()
         {
             return $this->classs->test_class();
         }
      }
```

Hope it will helps you.